# Problem with connect.sid and session in a node.js application, in production environment

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, session-cookies

The node application uses passport-ldap for authentication, and the issue is that it works like a charm in the development environment, but the are problems in the production one. When the route is being changed, I lose the user's session because  the connect.sid (the cookie) of the Application is being changed, because I have a new setCookie response.

I am using **express 4.17.1** and **express-session 1.16.2**, so from my research I found that i do not have to use cookieParser. I also think that there is no issue with the serialize and deserialize of the user and passport functionality.

```
// Static folder set
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body parser middleware

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.set('trust proxy', 1) //trust first proxy

// Express session midleware 
app.use(session({
  secret: 'abc',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

...

```
// Use routes of the application
app.use('/users', users);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and i post it for future reference, in case someone else faces a similar issue.

I used the cors module and set it like that

`app.use(cors({credentials: true}));`

also in production enviroment you have to use a store to hold the cookie. This was obvious but i missed it. So i used

```
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
  secret: 'abc',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { secure: true,
    maxAge:  6*60*60*1000 },
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));
```